# Is an epoch-based approach valid for modeling $N$-body systems?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, models, three-body-problem

Consider a 3-body Newtonian system with equal masses such that velocity change at a given time epoch for a single body is given by:

[image: equation]

I am interpreting that if $\vec{R_2}$ and $\vec{R_3}$ also change per epoch such that say $\dot{\vec{R_2}} = \dot{\vec{X_2}} - \dot{\vec{X_1}}$ which means $\ddot{\vec{X_1}}(t+2)$ has $\dot{\vec{X_1}}(t)$ as a component. So body state information propagates in a way that one could extrapolate this dynamic into a linear neural net to represent the entire system itself:

[image]

If such a shift in representation for such a fundamental problem was trivial like this, I would also expect to see it around more. So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't you (independently) reinvented [Euler's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) for numerically approximating differential equation solutions? It is indeed used a fair bit (without calling it a linear neural net), but  for serious applications it is too numerically unstable to be useful and other, more exact methods are used. Especially in mechanics where energy conservation applies one likes to use symplectic methods that ensures that the energy is conserved.

Comment: I am studying general system emergence, actually started with agent-based models of opinion dynamics that ended up somewhere seemingly unrelated, so excuse the jury-rigged terminology. Could you expand on a bit on where it is used vs what are serious applications it is not effective for? That would really help

Comment: Just start googling on numerical methods for solving differential equations - Euler's is almost always the first mentioned, and its shortcomings motivate the better methods people use. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_methods_for_ordinary_differential_equations https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-i-first-order-differential-equations/numerical-methods/  https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT-INF1100/h10/kompendiet/kap13.pdf